# Android Paypal Integration with MECL Issue

Tags: android, paypal, webserver, payment-gateway

I am trying to perform payments on an Android app via PayPal.

For this, I thought the most practical solution would be the MECL. However, the documentation claims that I must have a web server of my own, and that I must send a request from my mobile application to my web server, and then forward that request from my web server to the PayPal webserver.

My two questions are:
1) Is there a way to use MECL storing the credentials on the mobile device and sending the direct request to PayPal from the device?
2) Is there another PayPal library that allows sending the PayPal request directly from the mobile device?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use MPL if you do not want to use additional web server for PayPal in-app transactions

https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/PP_MPL_Developer_Guide_and_Reference_Android.pdf

Answer (score 0):

You already might know...Using setExpressCheckout method send the credentials to PayPal to handle the Pay operation and returns response as key and to conform(approve) the transaction within your web server page you have to use getExpressCheckout method to conform the transaction and based on your return URL it backs to your web server page.